# Capture All Heap Allocations

Tags: linux, debugging, trace, heap-memory, intel-pin

I want to find all accesses to *heap memory* in an application. I need to store each allocation and, consequently, can not only check for addresses in the `[heap]` range (which also does not include heap memory areas allocated by `mmap()`). Therefore, I wrote a `pintool` and captured all calls to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`. Because of optimizations such as tail-call elimiation `Pin` can not detect the last instruction of these calls. Therefore, I manually added callbacks after (precisely, I used `IPOINT_TAKEN_BRANCH`) the `ret...` instructions in each of the probable **direct/indirect jump targets** out of these functions (e.g., `malloc()`, indirectly, jumps to `malloc_hook_ini()`. So I added instrumentation code after all `ret...` instructions in `malloc_hook_ini()`). These targets, themselves, may have *outgoing* **direct/indirect jumps** and, again, I tried to capture them.

But, there are still some accesses in the `[heap]` range (and also in `mmap()` ranges) which do not pertain to any of the previously captured allocations. To clear up any doubts, I used [Pwngdb](https://github.com/scwuaptx/Pwngdb) to display all currently allocated heap chunks, right before the access point. The access address was clearly in an allocated heap chunk. Of course, knowing the allocation IP for these heap chunks will be a **great** help. But this is not supported in `Pwngdb` or any other similar tools.

In many cases analyzed by `Pin`, the access address does not belong to any address range allocated (even those removed in the meantime) during the whole program execution. How can I determine which allocation function was missed during `Pin` analysis?

It seems that there are two possible situations:

**1)** There exists some omitted function other than `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`.

**2)** There are some missed return points for `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`.

The **second candidate** is not possible. Because I put a counter before and after each of these allocation functions and at the end, they had *equal* values.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the backtrace for one such access point and also the value for the `RSI` register:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you would be better of doing this at the syscall level, aka intercepting all calls to the os for ram?

Comment: In general languages other than c may not use malloc to allocate their memory, and even c may use alternatives depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks. Interception at the system call level does not seem to help. Because (in `ptmalloc`) memory is **aggressively** obtained from the OS and stored in variable-sized chunks for **future** allocation. I need *actual* allocations. Could you mention a dynamic allocation mechanism in `C` that does not use `malloc()/calloc()/realloc()` or `mmap()`?

Comment: So someone could always `sbrk()` more memory, and use that? That seems like a plausible explanation. So you have further details on the heap accesses in question? Like a stacktrace or similar?

Comment: But memory allocation without using/updating `ptmalloc` metadata about the list of free chunks will put the allocator in an inconsistent state. I have added a dynamic memory access backtrace.

Comment: It's a long shot but are you correctly handling stuff like shared memory e.g. shmat? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html

Comment: Additionally are you sure you have no race conditions etc. with memory allocated on a different thread?

Comment: Thanks for your time. The program is single process. I found the bug. The reason was a silly mishandling of `calloc()` arguments. I thought that its input arguments are the same as that of `malloc()`.